# Why is "Amazon" written with strange characters in this URL?

Tags: amazon, url

When I do a search on Amazon France, one of the URL parameters is "ÅMÅŽÕÑ", as in the URL below:

`https://www.amazon.fr/s/ref=nb_sb_noss/256-9830746-1362835?__mk_fr_FR=ÅMÅŽÕÑ&url=search-alias%3Daps&field-keywords=Webcam`

Any idea why they have this strange parameter there?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

[Using special characters is a method to tell the browser to use UTF8 encoding](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/168751/is-the-use-of-utf8-preferable-to-utf8-true), and this probably is Amazon engineers putting in a bit of an easteregg instead of a dull `utf8=✓` thing.

For the record, all non-English versions have an `__mk_{languagecode}_{countrycode}` as URL parameter, the only one I found to differ from the ÅMÅŽÕÑ thing is the Japanese version, which uses カタカナ. カタカナ is Katakana spelled in Katakana.

Comment: That can be found on brazilian portuguese amazon too. :)